# Como crear un exe de 32 bits?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola tengo un problema y es que tengo un programa el cual lo pase a exe utilizando cx_freeze, pero el exe es de 64 bits y yo quiero que sea de 32 bits.

Como puedo conseguirlo?

Comment: No puedes hacer eso si estas usando una versión de 64 bits del intérprete Python. Simplemente instala una versión de 32 bits de Python, instala las librerias necesarias en ese intérprete (de 32 bist por suspuesto) incluido cx_freeze y crea el exe.

Comment: de donde puedo descargar todo eso. no encuentro python 32bit

Comment: En la pagina oficial de Python tienes todas las descargas, para 3.6.5: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-365/ Al final el que pone `Windows x86 executable installer` es la versión de 32 bits. Los paquetes los instalas vía `pip` asegurandote que instalas en esta versión.

Comment: pero y si ya tengo python 64 bits me afecta en algo